# qsort() on a 1-indexed array is messing up indexing

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I'm using a 1-indexed array that I'm trying to sort by profit/price ratios. I have a comparison function written out, it all works, but it's placing the first element in index 0. I would just move the elements over, but the array is quite large and this would add a significant amount to the time complexity

Does anyone know of a sort that would be compatible with an array of this type? As in one where I can specify the beginning of the array?

I tried using the following

```
qsort(problemCards+sizeof(Card), problemBank[i].getNumCards(), sizeof(Card), compare);
```

but I get an arithmetic error on one of the calls to the compare function....

I'm really trying to avoid having to write my own sort for this so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'd bet that `problemCards+sizeof(Card)` messes things up: use `+ 1` instead of `+ sizeof(Card)`. Of course, in C++ you'd be much better of using `std::sort()` anyway.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Ah! True! Completely forgot that incrementing a pointer by an integer x is automatically multiplied by the size of the element type within the array. That would mean I'm specifying an address way too far up in the array.

Comment: You tag stl but use the non-stl sort!?

Comment: @DietmarKühl How would you suggest using std:sort() for this situation? I tried changing it to +1 and it maintains the first index of the array at index 1, but the last index is lost and uninitialized. I then tried changing the size to size+1 - still no luck and same issue

Comment: @Riptyde4: you'll need a suitable strict weak order for your comparison using just a boolean rather than a tristate return (that is you won't be able use `compare()`). Ideally, you'd just define `operator<(Card const&, Card const&)` and then use `std::sort(problemCards + 1, problemCards + problemBank[i].getNumCards())`.

Comment: `std::sort(problemCards+1, problemCards + problemBank[i].getNumCards()+1, boolLesserYouNeedToWrite)` would be worth a shot, but *we can't reproduce your problem*, so the best you're going to get are wags (wild-ass-guesses). And add this as fuel to the "why I need to learn to use zero-based-indexing in C/C++" fire. Better still, a `std::vector<Card>`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: `.getNumCards()+1`, since it's a 1 based array.

Comment: @MooingDuck: who knows! ;-) ... but, yes, that's quite possible.

Comment: @Riptyde4: because STL algorithms take iterator pairs rather than counts (exception for the `_n`-versions).

Comment: What kind of array are you using? Why is it 1-indexed? Are you sorting the complete array (except for the zero element)? It would be nice to have a few more lines of code that show, what `Cards`, `problemCards` and  `compare` are.

Comment: @MikeMB It's a dynamically allocated array of my own defined Card class objects, it's a trivial part of a much larger assignment I was getting hung up on. I'm sorting baseball card objects by their profit to price ratios in decreasing order so that I can tackle the much harder task of solving the 0/1 knapsack problem. All is well now. It has to be 1-indexed as per the assignment

Comment: @Riptyde4 If your `Card` is non-POD, *you can't use qsort to sort them*.  Plain and simple, and there is no two-ways about it.  From this link:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort  *The type of the elements of the array must be a trivial type, otherwise the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Even if I define a compare function based on each objects member variables?

Comment: @Riptyde4  It isn't the compare function that is the issue -- it is the swapping of the objects that `qsort` would perform that is at issue.  If the object is non-POD, qsort() has no idea about this since it is a `C`-based function.  The `qsort` could be ripping your object to shreds using whatever swapping method is used.  That's why the link specifically says that the objects must be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to call `std::sort` with your data:

```
bool card_less( const Card& lhs, const Char& rhs ) {
  return compare(&lhs, &rhs)<0;
}

Card* start = problemCards+1;
Card* end = start + problemBank[i].getNumCards();
std::sort( start, end, card_less );
```

This assumes that `compare` is a free function that takes two `Card const*`.  We define `card_less` to be another free function that uses `compare` to tell you if the lhs is less than the rhs.

Comment: results in a seg fault :/

Comment: This also needs a check for empty set of cards

Comment: @MattMcNabb fortunately, that can never be the case if this sort is called

Comment: @matt that depends -- for an empty 1 based array `x`, do they guarantee that `x+1` is a valid address (not dereffed, just the address)?  I could pull that off by having 'empty' 1 based arrays point to a `char pempty[sizeof(Card)]`.  Sort of silly, but so are 1-based arrays.